# Display long text toast on android 12

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to display a long message in a toast (more than 5 lines) on android 12 but it results as the following

[image: toast message]

It displays only the first 2 lines and adds "..." to the end of the text

any solution to display the hole text?

Comment: May be Snackbar https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [Toast redesign](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12?hl=pl#toast-redesign).

> In Android 12, the toast view has been redesigned. Toasts are now
> limited to two lines of text and show the application icon next to the
> text.

Comment: Thank you google, you just making it worse and worse

Comment: @AlekDepler I agree with you about the toast, but there are much better alternatives to toast. Many other things had being improved by Google, so judging Google only for a toast (a simple short message purpose) is so much worse.

Comment: @AlekDepler yep, just like how they are making you run registerforactivityresult in OnCreate instead of just startActivityForResult... What the heck is Google thinking...

Answer (score 0):

from Android 12, the toast view has been redesigned. Toasts are now limited to two lines of text and show the application icon next to the text. To create a custom toast that allows for displaying long text, you can create a custom layout for your toast message. Here's how you can achieve this:

Here's an example implementation:

1. Create a custom layout file (e.g., custom_toast_layout.xml):

```html
<!-- custom_toast_layout.xml -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textViewToast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_toast_background"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

2. Create a method to show the custom toast:

```html
public void showCustomToast(Context context, String message) {
    // Inflate the custom layout
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_layout, null);
    
    // Set the message in the TextView
    TextView textView = layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewToast);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Create and show the toast
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

3. Call the showCustomToast method with your long text:

```html
String longMessage = "Your long toast message here...";
showCustomToast(context, longMessage);
```

With this implementation, you can display longer toast messages compared to the system toast, as the custom toast layout can accommodate more text. Adjust the layout properties (e.g., text size, padding) as needed to fit your design preferences.